# Write a tiff stack with python and keep file name

Tags: python, image, tiff

I have a folder with 5 tiff images that I want to put together in one stack file.

img01.tiff, img20.tiff, img25.tif, img30.tif, img50.tif

Afte processing I would like to convert that stack into single images, and conserve the file name.

To stack I do:

```
import tifffile as tiff
import os
from natsort import natsorted

path='img_folder'
output_filename='stack.tiff'
with tiff.TiffWriter(output_filename, bigtiff=True) as tif_writer:
    for idx, filename in enumerate(natsorted(os.listdir(path))):
        print(filename)
        img=tiff.imread(os.path.join(path,filename),name=filename)
        tif_writer.save(img)
```

I tried writing on the description parameter or metadata (Info as well as Labels) but it did not work:

```
tif_writer.save(img, photometric='minisblack', metadata={'Info': filename}, description=filename)
```

In any case the file name information is lost or I don't now how to access it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/0b6a4355225c750262838558eaab51a5f4614540/tifffile/tifffile.py#L1309-L1312),

> [description & metadata are] saved with the first page of a series only.

*EDIT: I updated this example to include the two options suggested by @cgohlke*

#### Option 1: Write separate series

By default using `TiffWriter.write` or `TiffWriter.save` sequentially like this will create a separate *series* in the resulting image and save the description to the first *page* in each series.

```py
import numpy as np
import tifffile

with tifffile.TiffWriter('temp.tif') as tif:
  for i in range(4):
    filename = f"image_{i}"
    img = np.random.randint(0, 1023, (256, 256), 'uint16')
    tif.save(img, photometric='minisblack', description=filename)


with tifffile.TiffFile('temp.tif') as tif:
  for series in tif.series:
    first_page = series[0]
    print(first_page.description)
  
  # tif.asarray returns the first series by default, 
  # so `key` is needed to create the stack from multiple series.
  stack = tif.asarray(key=slice(None))
  print(stack.shape)

# image_0
# image_1
# image_2
# image_3
# (4, 256, 256)
```

#### Option 2: Write one series

By setting `metadata=None`, you can write individual pages to the same series and iterate over the pages to get the descriptions.

```py
import numpy as np
import tifffile

with tifffile.TiffWriter('temp.tif') as tif:
  for i in range(4):
    filename = f"image_{i}"
    img = np.random.randint(0, 1023, (256, 256), 'uint16')
    tif.save(img, photometric='minisblack', description=filename, metadata=None)


with tifffile.TiffFile('temp.tif') as tif:
  for page in tif.pages:
    print(page.description)

  stack = tif.asarray() # no need for `key` because pages in same series
  print(stack.shape)

# image_0
# image_1
# image_2
# image_3
# (4, 256, 256)
```

Comment: Almost there. `tif.asarray()` returns the first series in the file by default. In this case it returns an array of shape `(256, 256)`. You might want to stack the images from all pages (`stack = tif.asarray(key=slice(None))`) or not write series in the first place (`tif.save(..., metadata=None)`) and then iterate over the pages to get the descriptions.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the example to use `key=slice(None)`.

Comment: Hello,
Sorry for the late reply.

Somehow it does not work for me.

On the first option I get this:

image_0
(4, 256, 256)

It seems there is only one series in tif.series .



In the second option I get this output:
image_0
image_1
image_2
image_3
image_0
(4, 256, 256)

(4, 256, 256)

(4, 256, 256)

(4, 256, 256) . 

Somehow only the fist page has a description. The other descriptions are empty.

I understand the code and I think it should work, but I don't know what is happening.

I am using tifffile                  2020.7.24                pypi_0    pypi

Comment: (The source says that description is "Saved with the first page of a series
            only."     I don't know if this is the problem.)

Comment: Hi,
I updated tifffile package and now it works! Thank you
I use tifffile                  2020.10.1 now.